# How to retrieve AppleID of logged in user via CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, apple-id

I figured out how to retrieve **first** / **lastName** of a logged in user. Is there a way to get the AppleID too?!

```
var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    defaultContainer.discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID(recordID, {userInfo, error in

        println("firstName: \(userInfo.firstName?) lastName: \(userInfo.lastName?)")

        })
```

Comment: By Apple Id, you mean the user's email address?

Comment: yes, user's e-mail address what you use to log in on the authentication window

Comment: I believe that's the whole point of the UserRecordId, so that apple would give you some sort of mechanism to track that user in the context of your application, but without the need for the user to give out too much private information, like his email address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the current user's email address - you're going to have to ask for it outside of CloudKit. This is a privacy thing. You're supposed to use the `UserRecordId` to uniquely identify users.

You *can*, however, search for other users if you already *know* their email address with [`CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation).

Comment: Hey, CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation sounds great but I can't find anything about it. Could you show how I can check whether the user's email address is same a string using this class?

Comment: @LinusG. I'm not really sure how to do that - I've only played around with CloudKit a little bit. That might be worth asking a new question, though.