# CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation usage

Tags: ios, swift, email

I want to find out whether a certain user is using my swift application. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806589/3397217) that CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation is made exactly for doing this. Since neither the answer nor Apple's docs provide any information on how to use it and I did not find anything useful anywhere else I am asking for help.

So I'd appreciate anyone being so kind and helping me out here :)